# Are those dead pixels? "Dead Pixel Detect and Fix" apk did not work with them

Tags: screen, hardware

I have a new LG L9 for about 2-3 days now (but it came to me without foil on the screen).

Today I've noticed that about 1-3 pixels near the middle of the screen are quite black. And they do not react to color changes like other pixels of the screens - whenever they should be black, red, white - they just stay the same color (they are easy to spot on white background and hard to detect on any other color).

**When I change the viewing angle, they disappear gradually.** So **they react to angle a lot**. When I have my phone in front of my eyes, I see them good. But when I look from the very low angle (screen is in the corner of my eyes, I look from far left/right side) - they are not visible on the screen.

**Is that typical for dead pixels? Or they are not dead pixels at all?**

**Is it possible to fix them?**

It's hard to make s photo of them, because my camera makes a bit too blured photos (so those pixels are not as visible as in real life) - **those are the same, viewed from different angles**: 
[image]
[image]

I've downloaded and run the **Dead Pixel Detect and Fix** application, but it didn't fix them.

I use Android 4.

Comment: What's that "Dead Pixel Detect and Fix" thing? How could a piece of software possibly detect _and fix_ a hardware failure?

Comment: @JanDvorak - from other questions and from Google I've found that many people suggest to use that apk. It's quite popular on Google Play - about 3.000 downloads and quite good score. I guess it's for some software-dependent pixel bugs only, anyway.

Comment: Games, toys, pranks etc. can also have high downloads and reasonable (at first sight) ratings. Things as a flashlight (turns your screen white), cracked screen (not really), fingerprint scanners (with footnotes), night vision goggles (actually just a really crappy green effect that reduces the worse-than-eyes camera sensitivity even further), heart rate monitors (place a finger on your wrist, then tap on the screen, and we'll measure the frequency), mind readers (maybe they can read voice expressions better than some people can, but probably not) ... can be quite popular.

Comment: Ok, I also thought that this apk has a limited usage, but can we focus on the main part of the question? You can just ignore I've used it (it was a fast & costless step, so I thought "why not give it a try?").

Comment: Changing a pixel rapidly between black and white (or subpixels between fully on and off, what this app does) *may* get it unstuck. It does not detect dead pixels itself, just sets the whole screen to the same color so *you* can detect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dead pixel is a class of manufacturing defects on screens which causes a pixel or sub pixel to remain permanently on or permanently off. The actual [cause of dead or stuck pixel varies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_pixel), and while some may fix itself over time, but many are permanent. Basically, as long as the pixel are stuck on a color that it shouldn't be, it can be considered a dead pixel. So yes, you have a dead pixel.

Depending on the device, the number and type of dead pixel, the manufacturer, and the seller you buy the item from, dead pixel may be covered under warranty. Check your warranty information on how to get a warranty and also ask the store you buy your device from, and you might be able to get a replacement. If this is a brand new device, some stores may replace even when the warranty doesn't require them to (under store policy, not manufacturer's).